# Startup disc creator not allowing any iso to be loaded

Tags: startup-applications, disk-utility

i have 12.04 , ubuntu, and startup diskcreator isn't allowing the program to see the iso. 
root perms
it just doesn't load it. the usb loads fine though.

Answer (score 3):

If the .iso file was downloaded as by root for some reason it could be unreadable by your regular account. You can open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the command`sudo chmod a+r the-image.iso` to fix that.

I assume you are using usb-creator-gtk, the standard Ubuntu tool for this. I've had some trouble selecting the iso file I want with that program because of the small window available to select files. Let me suggest starting it from a terminal by using

```
usb-creator-gtk -i the-image.iso
```

Comment: If I misunderstand what is going on, please add the command you are using and the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work, i'm not getting any error at cmd line, and nothing in the logs.

Comment: sudo usb-creator-gtk -i the-image.iso
did the trick for me... 
:-)

Answer (score 1):

This was solved for me by removing any .img files from the folder where the desired Ubuntu iso is located. 
 So basically, I had an Android boot.img inside the same folder as the Ubuntu 12.04.1 iso, which is what I wanted to use for startup-disk-creator. I moved the boot.img to a separate folder, re-opened startup-disk-creator, and it worked. I don't know if it's a quirk with specifically choosing img files over iso files; or if there is a general issue with having two or more startup-disk compatible files inside the same folder, I just know that isolating the Ubuntu iso from other types of startup files solved the issue for me.

Comment: A strange error if true - it would need to be reported as a bug since it shouldn't matter if there are .img files in the same folder.